# Blogger javascript conflict with label search

Tags: javascript, label, blogger

first time asking. I've been costuming a blogger template - http://personalist-themexpose.blogspot.com - and learning code as I go. But now I'm stuck.

When I click on a post label, the page starts loading but before it ends, it goes blank. After some fiddling I'm convinced the is some sort of conflict with two javacript applications.

I found out that by deleting the last lines of the pagination plugin I would be able to go into the /search/label/… pages, but I don't know how that will affect the overall workings of the page. [edit] This solves the problem when viewing fem the desktop. The issue persists when viewing from the phone - @media?

```
else {
    document.write('<script src="' + home_page + 'feeds/posts/full/-/' + lblname1 + '?alt=json-in-script&callback=showpageCount2&max-results=99999" ><\/script>')
}
```

But when viewing a label page the simple menu on the left side won't work.
Another thing I noticed is that removing script relating to the menu will also allow me to go into a label page but obviously results in the menu malfunctioning:

```
<script src='http://yourjavascript.com/8118243424/min.js' type='text/javascript'/>
```

I've never ever worked with javascript and am a total noob in html so sorry for not being able to give more technical hints.

The designer of this template has got a very similar one which works fine, only it doesn't have the side menu. This tells me that the issue reside probably in the code for this menu. Can someone tell me how to resolve this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

So anyway, I solved the issue. I was right to thing that the menu was the culprit. I downloaded the link to the javascript posted in the question which ended up being an amalgam of different plugins. In the end there was the script referring to the [Sidr](http://www.berriart.com) menu. I downloaded the original script from the Sidr website and replaced the adulterated one with it in the amalgam file - I wasn't able to separate the plugins without destabilizing the template. Ran the website and all was working.